# qmake: compile single cpp file into an executable

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I got a project in QT and I'd like to use qmake for compiling one additional cpp file that (into standalone executable) is not connected in any way to my application or even QT (it's very simple plain C++ program). Is there any way to do this without rebulding whole project structure? Do I need separate `.pro` file for every executable or is there any other way for simple compiling just one, plain C++ file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an additional executable you can use use [`system()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-function-reference.html#system-command) in .pro like so:

```
system(g++ otherapp.cpp)
```

Which will be built every time you call `qmake`. However if you want to build the additional app automatically when its source is changed, use [QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-custom-targets) instead.

Comment: QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGET was what I needed. I had also to add target to PRE_TARGETDEPS and now everything is done automatically when QT Creator compiles project. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As you may know `qmake -project` will make one `.pro` file with the name of the folder containing your whole  source and header files, if you qmake this pro file then `make` your project you will get compiled `.o` file from your new cpp file even if it's not connect to your Qt project directly.

but if this file got `main()` function of course you will have multiple main() definitions error by compiler.

you will need to rebuild that file of course

as you know for simple compiling of only one standard plain c++ file you just

```
g++ source.cpp -o excutable_name.exe
```

for more strict compiling with two steps:

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic -ansi source.cpp -c compiled_file_name.o
g++  compiled_file_name -o excutable_name.exe
```

but if you are going to use for example a code related to Qt, you have to include Qt headers and link necessary libraries :

```
g++ -Wall source.cpp -c compiled_file_name.o -L qt/library/path -lQtGui -lQtCore  -lQtother_necessary_libraries -I Qt/include/path -I Qtother_necessary_include_paths
```

Comment: I'd like to do everything by using only one command (`qmake project.pro`) like QT Creator does it (which I'm using to compile my project). Is that possible without subdirs template?

Comment: you want to make compiling for one plain c++ file, or several files?. if several complex files it's better for you to use make tools like qmake or cmake, but if only one plain c++ file you can just use `g++` command line directly